# Group similar words in a large vector (300k)

Tags: r

I have a large character around 300K, and I want to get a unique list of similar words in the list. Clustering won't work as the number of cluster will change from application to application.

Suppose the data looks like so:

```
x = as.vector(c('accuracy','accuracy','friendliness','friendliness','email','email_','email_hi',`email_asdlk`))
```

As you can see, there are 3 clusters here, `accuracy` `friendliness` and `email`

using `stringdistmatrix` on a size of 300k takes way to long. What other options are there?